# Git push gives an error after loading repo and making some changes in the project

Tags: git, authentication, github

I did `git init` + `git pull` to load my repository. Git haven't asked me about any auth despite this repo is private (I earlier used it and connected to this repo so maybe this is the reason). So then I made some changes in this local project and after that I tried `git push`. This caused an error:

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>
```

This one looks like a popular error in the internet but people have it when they really don't have connection to the repo so they have to connect. But in my case I firstly did `git pull` so I'd have it.

Comment: What's the result of `git remote -v` (list remote repositories)?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking two things:

1. Do you have a remote setted ?

The given error message seem to indicated that no remote are setted. So if you try to run `git remote -vv`, it should give you a result as:

```
origin  url-to-your-repository.git (fetch)
origin  url-to-your-repository.git (push)
```

If not, please add a remote with `git remote add`.
If you do have a remote specified, please verify that you do have the authorization to push on the remote. Sometime, private repository allow pulling codebase, but restrict pushing.

2. If you are sure that you have all authorization, you should check if you have a remote branch specified for your local branch with `git branch -vv`:

```
* feature-name 51ff531 [origin/remote-feature-name] Commit message
```

Here in my example, my local branch `feature-name` is linked to my `origin` remote branch named `remote-feature-name` (specified in `[]`).
Depending on your git configuration, `git push` command could need you to specify a remote and a branch name such as `git push origin feature-name`.